# Domain mapping / aliassing to subdomain

Tags: subdomain

We have a VPS (cpanel/whm) for hosting several website, each site is created in subdomain

- one.domain.com, two.domain.com, three.domain.com, etc.

now we want to have unique domain for every subdomain

- www.web-one.com -> one.domain.com, www.web-two.com -> two.domain.com, etc

how to configure the domain masking/mapping/aliasing so when customer visit the url bar shows:

- www.web-one.com/folder/one.html instead of one.domain.com/folder/one.html

Comment: Ask on [stackoverflow.com](stackoverflow.com) Tag with .htaccess, rewrite. Question Title-> How to redirect old domain to newd-domain while preserving the path? (I assume that you have moved all the services to web-one.com from one.domain.com)

Comment: Do you have any options to point the DNS records of the subdomain to your new IP? Some registar's give the option to alias (aka mask) as well.